# postgres column allow space to column while making alias name

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

python code to make query from postgres table

```
query = "select species as `flower name` from iris"
connection = db_connect(connection_data)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(""" {} """.format(query))
```

error:

```
File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/report/backend/api/utils/fetch_data.py", line 34, in get_query_result
    cursor.execute(""" {} """.format(query))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1:  select species as `flowers` from iris
```

I wants to add space to alias name of column thats why i have written my code like this.
Plese check how can i fix it.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres follows the SQL standard and uses double quotes, not backticks, to escape database object names (such as column or table names).  Use this version:

```py
query = 'SELECT species AS "flower name" FROM iris'
connection = db_connect(connection_data)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: And for mysql what changes i need to do ? tim

Comment: Your current query string is fine for MySQL, but double quotes as in my answer will also work there.